# How to notify Composition if a public property of Stable type changes?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As stated in the Jetpack compose documentation, a stable type must comply with the following contract.

1. The result of equals for two instances will forever be the same for
   the same two instances.
2. If a public property of the type changes, Composition will be notified.
3. All public property types are also
   stable.

The first and third contracts are straightforward. How can I comply with the second point?

For example, I have a stable type called `User`

```
data class User(val username: String, var email: String)
```

and I change the email during the flow of the app, how can I notify the Composition?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Jetpack Compose Stability Explained](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8):

> It’s important to note that the parameters don’t have to be immutable, they can be mutable as long as the Compose runtime is notified of all changes. For most types this would be an impractical contract to uphold however Compose provides mutable classes that do uphold this contract for you e.g `MutableState`, `SnapshotStateMap`/`List`/etc. As a result, using these types for your mutable properties will allow your class to uphold the contract of `@Stable`.

The example from the same post suggests ensuring any `var` in your class is actually a `MutableState`:

```kotlin
@Stable
class MyStateHolder {
  var isLoading by mutableStateOf(false)
}
```

In your example, it could be something like this:

```kotlin
@Stable
data class User(val username: String) {
  var email by mutableStateOf("")
}
```

Note that at this point a `data class` may not be desirable, as some of the functionality it generates (`copy`, `equals`) wouldn't work with the now-mutable email field.

Answer (score -2):

Compose has a special `State` type that allows you to notify when a recomposition is needed. This is the most common way to initiate a recomposition.

The `data` class is a good tool that will give you `copy` for all fields out of the box, but you should avoid using `var` and use only `val` for your fields to avoid mistakes.

So, a basic example of updating a field would look like this:

```
var state by remember { mutableStateOf(User(username = "", email = "")) }
TextField(
    value = state.username,
    onValueChange = {
        state = state.copy(username = it)
    }
)
```

You can use `Flow`/`LiveData` in the same way, since they can be collected in `State` with `collectAsState`/`observeAsState`.

More info can be found in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Comment: You haven't answer the question. How to notify composition when a public property changes, period